# Seemingly easy Question concerning parametric lines: if $z= 0.5x + 0.5y $ , show that $\|x-z\|=\|y-z\|$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

The parametric equation I am working with assumes that two points $x,y$ lie on the line, which can be understood as going in the direction $y-x$, thus the equation will be, $x(t)= (1-t)x + ty $
For $t= 0.5$ I get the equation in the question. But am no closer to getting an answer.
So please help me out.

Comment: $z = 0.5 x + 0.5y \implies 0.5x - 0.5z = 0.5z - 0.5y$. Take the length.

Comment: That's it? Only this is needed for finding the midpoint of $l(x,y)$

Comment: Yes. Graphically, $z$ is the midpoint of $l(x,y)$. So the distance between $z$ and $x$ should be equal to that between $z$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(t) = ty+(1-t)x = x + t(y-x)$.

Note that $p(t)-p(s) = (t-s)(y-x)$.

Then $z-x = {1 \over 2}(y-x)$ and $y-z = {1 \over 2}(y-x)$.

Comment: What is p(s) in the second step and what is its use?

Comment: $p(s)$ is $p$ evaluated at $s$????? Its use is to help you prove the result you are looking for.

Comment: Please bear with me I need to finish this chapter tonight and haven’t slept much

Comment: I still don’t understand the proof can you pleas elaborate?

Comment: Show that $z-x = {1 \over 2}(y-x)$ and $y-z = {1 \over 2}(y-x)$ and then take the norm of $z-x, y-z$.

Comment: What do you mean by taking the norm ? Will I have to prove that they satisfy the three basic properties of euclidean length? How will that be relevant to proving that the midpoint occurs when $t=0.5$ ?

Comment: You have lost me. You asked to prove $\|z-x\| = \|y-z\|$. What is $\|z-x\|$ if $z-x = {1 \over 2}(y-x)$?

Comment: The midpoint distance.

Comment: Using the expression I have above, what is $\|z-x\|$ in terms of $\|y-x\|$?

Comment: They are lengths which are equal as per your proof